# Axis2 Timeout waiting for connection

Tags: apache, apache-axis

My code is consistently generating the following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Timeout waiting for connection
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:203)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

After extensive searching the solution appears to be here:

http://amilachinthaka.blogspot.com/2009/05/improving-axis2-client-http-transport.html

Except I cannot access http client directly (that is done in auto generated code).

Instead I have tried:

http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AxisCommonsHTTP

Which seems to help slightly.  However it only delays the problem I always get the timeout.  Also the instructions appear to be for an old version of Axis since Axis2 does not have AxisProperties.  I am using version 1.5.1.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was a bug, see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4752) and has been fixed with Axis2 1.5.2 (at least for generated code). With custom code, you need to tackle this problem manually.